# Rails Model.find key not found, Model.where key found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, key, parameters

```
Page.find(permalink: 'home')
# => Page.find(permalink: 'home')                                                                                                                        
# => ArgumentError: Unknown key: permalink

Page.where(permalink: 'home')
# => [#<Page id: 1, permalink: "home", content: "foo", created_at: "2014-05-14 01:54:06", updated_at: "2014-05-14 01:54:06">]
```

**Route**

```
get ':permalink', to: 'page#show', as: :page
```

**Model**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :permalink
end
```

**Controller**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @page = Page.find(permalink: params[:permalink])
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new page_params

    if @page.valid?
      redirect_to @page
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @page = page.find(params[:permalink])

    if @page.update(page_params)
      redirect_to @page
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def edit
    @page = page.find params[:permalink]
  end

  private

  def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:permalink, :content)
  end
end
```

Am I doing something off here?

Comment: `find` is used to query by `id`: `find(12)`, to query by `permalink` use `find_by_permalink('permalink')`

Comment: But since Rails 4 such finders are deprecated, so it's better to use `where(...).first`

Comment: @SergeyKishenin Dynamic finders like `find_by_permalink('home')` were deprecated in 4.0, but in Rails 4+, you'll want to use: `Page.find_by(permalink: 'home')`. `find_by(...)` is faster/doesn't do an `order by` in the SQL, and is less to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how the `find` method works. Take a look at [the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object). You pass it a single primary key that may or may not be in the database, not a hash. The where method can take in a hash, or a string.

```
Page.find(1)
# => [#<Page id: 1, permalink: "home", content: "foo", created_at: "2014-05-14 01:54:06", updated_at: "2014-05-14 01:54:06">]

Page.where(permalink: "home", content: "foo")
# => [#<Page id: 1, permalink: "home", content: "foo", created_at: "2014-05-14 01:54:06", updated_at: "2014-05-14 01:54:06">]
```

Comment: *sigh* derp. Always the small things.

Comment: @Lemur No problem! It happens to all of us!

Comment: Don't forget, in Rails 4+ you can also use `find_by(permalink: "home")`, which is faster than `where(permalink: "home").first` to find a single record. (Prior to that there were dynamic finder methods like `find_by_permalink('`home')` but those were deprecated in ActiveRecord 4.0.)